# How to implement a bottom navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm very new to Android development so i'm sure i'm making beginners mistakes here. I'm trying to implement a bottom navigation bar by following this guide here: https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android

I've downloaded the demo project and it works. I'm now trying to copy the code for the bottom navigation and make it work in another android studio project and am getting this error.

[image]

I think the cause of this error is this piece of xml in my main activity where it's referencing the bottom_nav_items i am trying to have show:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```

I think this is to do with the folder structure I have. The demo project has a different folder structure to my project.

[image: Demo Project]

[image: Demo Project]

Where as the project I have created has this folder structure.

[image: My Project]

[image: My Project]

I think the problem is when I add folders in my project the folder doesn't appear in the package folder whereas in the demo project this is the case.

EDIT ---------------

This is my buildgradle (Project Celebreak) file :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lewisblack.celebreak"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com/lewisblack/celebreak/model']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/menu']
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add this in layout :

```
   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottomdrawer"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottomdrawer"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

then add menu like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_life"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/bottom_main"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/bottom_contact"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_social"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/bottom_social"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_application"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/bottom_app"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/bottom_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then in your Activity implement this :

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
```

also make sure you had this in Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

For more attributes of `BottomNavigationView` see the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having tried this I got the error 'No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'android' '. In my build gradle for module app I have the compile statement aswell.

Comment: Is that the build.gradle (Project: Project name) file or build.gradle (Module: App)  file? And if it is the project file where in the file do I add it?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: The above is in my build.gradle file (Project: Projectname) file

Comment: looks ok..please `synch project with gradle file` press it in top bar..and clean build the project..

Answer (score 0):

It is not `design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"`, it should be `app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this based on yours and rafsanahmad007 answers and I have a new error 'No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package 'android'. On a side note the demo app worked with design being there but I am looking through the documentation because i don't understand the meaning of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `menu` as Directory not as Android Resource Directory and then paste your `bottom_nav_items.xml` in it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.3 they have provided this at the start of new project. Create new project and choose the bottom navigation for the start activity of your project and study their code as they provide the perfect code.

You will get other codes but, google will provide the best.

Good Luck!